# Load file - is instance

Tags: python, function

I am reading the following lines of code - and I was wondering why one wants to do check whether the instance of the file is equal to the type of an empty string? any tips much appreciated

```
def load(file):
    if isinstance(file, type("")):
        file = open(file, "rb")
    return file.read()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `file` is not a string, `open(file, "rb")` is certain to fail with an error. Hence, the check against `type("")`, which is guaranteed to be `<str>`. The `return` statement should properly also be inside the if conditional for the same reason: trying to do `.read()` on anything other than a file object will almost certainly fail with an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an implementation of something resembling strongly typed languages. Since Python is weakly typed you don't have to decalre the type of variable you'll be using and for someone who is not sure how will his function be used by others it's just an assurance policy.

Answer (score 0):

It is just another writing for:

```
...
if isinstance(file, str):
    ...
```

because `type('')` **is** `str` (be it in Python 2 or Python 3)